# show/hide prstashop products to a visitors depending on thier country visit

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I want a full module code that can show or hide products for some countries, I have products that I can send to anywhere and some that I can only send to some counties and others I can only send localy.

I tried this but I don't know what I did wrong
I created a file inside modules folder and made this code

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/functions.php');
class MyIpModule extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'myipmodule';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Your Name';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My IP Module');
        $this->description = $this->l('Module that translates visitor IP address to country code.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('filterProductSearch');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    public function hookFilterProductSearch($params)
    {
        $ip = Tools::getRemoteAddr();
        $country_code = ip_info($ip, "Country Code");

        // Use $country_code as needed to filter search results
    }
}
```

I then created a folder named translations.
Inside the translations folder,  I create a file named en.php and add the following code:

```
<?php
$_MODULE = array(
    'myipmodule' => 'My IP Module',
    'Module that translates visitor IP address to country code.' => 'Module that translates visitor IP address to country code.',
);
```

and the I include the functions.php file in the module file:

```
<?php

function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
    $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
        "NA" => "North America",
        "SA" => "South America"
    );
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
            switch ($purpose) {
                case "location":
                    $output = array(
                        "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                        "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                        "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                        "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                        "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                        "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                    );
                    break;
                case "address":
                    $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                    break;
                case "city":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    break;
                case "state":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "region":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                    break;
                case "countrycode":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

?>
```

Comment: I think it's better to use Prestashop's "multiShop" feature

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel there are good paid addons module that fulfill your requirements.

Comment: thanks but I love challenge, would love to see my module works

Comment: You are far behind what you need actually to create this feature, unfortunately

It won't be that easy, and you'd have to modify every single SQL query that checks for products in PrestaShop to hide those you don't want to show for a given country